# How to restrict the public access

Tags: amazon-s3

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "IPAllow",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::SOMENAME/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": "https://odoweb.web.app"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In developer tools / Network / got:

```
Referer: https://odoweb.web.app/sometext/someid
```

But every request is denied from any domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "IPAllow",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::SOMENAME/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": "https://odoweb.web.app*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```